# How to get the text of all elements in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I want to fetch all the `li` texts of suggestions after entering in the google search bar "Webdriver". I have wrote some code like this:

```
 this.getElements = function(){
  element.all(by.css('ul.sbsb_b')).then(function(text){
      for(var i=0; i < text.length;i++)
      {
          console.log(text[i].getText());
      }
  });
};
```

On execution I m getting something like:

```
{ ptor_: 
  { controlFlow: [Function],
     schedule: [Function],
     getSession: [Function],
     getCapabilities: [Function],
     quit: [Function],
```

instead of text values of Suggestions.

Comment: getText() doesn't return the text. It returns a promise: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText

Answer (score 19):

There is a set of javascript array-like functions in Protractor that allows you to `filter()` or `map()` result of async promise. For example if original `element.all(by.css('something'))` would return list of `ElementFinder`s, `map()` allows to transform it into array of `getText()`s, which in resolved state is just an array of strings. You can then use it however you want.

```
element.all(by.css('something')).map(function(elm) {
  return elm.getText();   
}).then(function(texts) {
  texts.forEach(...);
});
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained your code a bit.

Comment: +1 for map() so I can do this: `elements() { return $$('li').map(e => e.getText()) as Promise<string[]>; }`

Answer (score 7):

We need to specify getText() to get list of text in element.all

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li>Home</li>
   <li> About Us</li>  
</ul> 

element.all(by.css('.menu li')).getText().then(function(menus) {
    expect(menus.length).toBe(2); //true
    console.log(menus);
});
```

**log output**

```
['Home','About Us']
```

Need more [helper function](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md)

Answer (score 4):

For looping through every element, you can also do something like:

```
element.all(by.css('ul.sbsb_b')).each(function(element, index) {
    element.getText().then(function(text) {
        console.log(text);
    });
});
```

http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each

Answer (score 2):

To print the value from getText(), you need to resolve the promise using .then()

Something like this:

```
text[i].getText().then(function(textValue)
{
    console.log(textValue);
});
```

Regards,
Sakshi

Comment: Could you elaborate it with an working example. I am newbie in this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should do next

```
this.getElements = function(){
  element.all(by.css('ul.sbsb_b')).getText().then(function(text){
      console.log(text);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an old question but still when i did someElementSelector.getText(); i got a string instead of array, so i split the string based on '\n'

example

```
someElementSelector.getText().then(function(text){
  var arrayA = text.split("\n");
// this gives me ['one','two','three'] 
})
```

This gives us the array of text from an element which has  multiple texts.

Comment: Please do not ask questions in answers. After making sure that your question has not been answered already, ask a new question keeping in mind the [**how to ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: Im sorry let me edit what i posted was an answer LOL. I will rephrase my answer