# How to handle more than one element on Page with same xpath

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

I have more than one element on page which has same xpath and same id/name
, 
there are two fields on page with same locators i tried to enter value at desired location with below code

element.all(by.xpath('//*[@id="testInstanceScan"]')).get(1).sendKeys('Vkumar');

but I faced error message:

Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 1, but there are only 1 elements that match locator By(xpath, //*[@id="testInstanceScan"]
)

if i used
element.all('#testInstanceScan').get(1).sendKeys('Vkumar');

i faced error

Failed: Invalid locator
  Stack:
    TypeError: Invalid locator

Xpath:

```
 //*[@id="TubeExpirationDate"]
```

please suggest me on this.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried and relevant html.

Comment: var expDate= browser.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="TubeExpirationDate"]'));
     
        expDate.clear();
        expDate.sendKeys('11252017');
        browser.driver.sleep(4000);

there i m trying to enter date into date filed and have 3 datefiled with same xpath('//*[@id="TubeExpirationDate"]')

Comment: Do you want to enter the same value to all the elements? Also it'll be easier to read if you respond by editing your answer (including your code above).

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick response,

if i can identify such same element i can enter the desired value whether it is duplicate or duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `element.all(locator).each(eachFunction)`, similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29605298/6205848). `element.all()` returns a List of the element identified by the common locator. `.each()` then loops through that List. The `function(element, index)` that is passed into `.each()` gives you access to each element and its index.

```
element.all(by.id('TubeExpirationDate')).each(function(element, index) {
    element.clear();
    var date = index + 3;
    element.sendKeys('11' + date + '2017');
});
```

As suggested by others, [protractortest.org](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all) is a great resource to take the time to review.

Comment: Hi i Tried with element and but my application is not launching
below is the code which i am using
for(var i=1;element.all(by.xpath('//*[@id="TubeExpirationDate"]')).count();i++ ){
                element.all('//*[@id="TubeExpirationDate"]').get(i).clear;
                element.all('//*[@id="TubeExpirationDate"]').get(i).sendKeys('11252017');
                browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        }
and below is:

Tube Lot Exp. Date
   [................]
   [................]
   [................]

i am not able to attach the screenshot so tried to show the desired field

Comment: Edited my answer with more clarification and added a line to modify the sendKey value

Answer (score 0):

Check [`element.all()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) and [`filter()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) or [`each()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) something like [`cssContainingText()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText) on the Protractor API Page.

to improve your code (which doesn't work):

```
for (var i=1;element.all(by.xpath('//*[@id="TubeExpirationDate"]')).c‌​ount();i++ ){
    element.all('//*[@id="TubeExpirationDate"]').get(i).clear;
    element.all('//*[@id="TubeExpirationDate"]').get(i).sendKeys‌​('11252017');
    browser.driver.sleep(2000);
}
```

try in example this:

```
let j = 0;
let entries = ['july', 'august', 'september', 'restOfYear'];
$$('#TubeExpirationDate').each(function(elem){
    elem.clear().sendKeys('11'+entries[j]+'2017');
    j++;
    //browser.sleep(2000); //I suggest not to use browser.sleep at all
})
```

But better would be to clearly identify the exact object you'd like to send your input by [using CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for unique identification. Such as:

```
let elemGroup = $$('#TubeExpirationDate');
elemGroup.$('div[indiv-index ="0"]').clear().sendKeys('11-01-2017');
elemGroup.$('div[indiv-index ="1"]').clear().sendKeys('11-02-2017');
//or if you want to use a counter-variable
elemGroup.$('div[indiv-index ="'+j+'"]').clear().sendKeys('11'+entries[j]+'2017');
```

But as I already suggested, do also some research on [Protractortest.org](http://www.protractortest.org) ... so many good explanations and examples are available there.

Comment: @ Ernst Zwingli 
Thank you for our suggestion,
With above code i am able to enter values in each element, however  from my code(which doesn't work) i was supposing to enter different value for each element.
like 
var j=i+3
element.all('//*[@id="TubeExpirationDate"]').get(i).sendKeys‌​('11'+j+'2017');
is there any other way for similar input.

Comment: @vijaykumar :  improved my answer. There is no rocket science in these things, so also take the chance to inform yourself about via protractortest.org.